# RXJS map operator returns empty response

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, asp.net-core, rxjs

First, `package.json` :

```
"@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
"rxjs": "6.2.1",
```

I am following a asp.net core 2 with angular tutorial. I had to adapt some code because it was thought for an older version.

The chapter is about creating JWT authentication.

I get the bearer token but when the `api controller` returns the response the `auth.service` gets an empty response and the line `let token = res && res.token;` goes false for the `if` so it never gets identified.

I suspect there is something wrong with the cast for TokenResponse but I cannot figure out what.

**token.response.ts**

```
interface TokenResponse {
    token: string,
    expiration: number
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { EventEmitter, Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID } from "@angular/core";
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    authKey: string = "auth";
    clientId: string = "NetCoreAngularWeb";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {
    }

    // performs the login
    login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
        var url = "api/token/auth";
        var data = {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            client_id: this.clientId,
            // required when signing up with username/password
            grant_type: "password",
            // space-separated list of scopes for which the token is 
            // issued
            scope: "offline_access profile email"
        };

        return this.http.post<TokenResponse>(url, data)
            .pipe(
                map(res => {
                    let token = res && res.token;
                    // if the token is there, login has been successful
                    if (token) {
                        // store username and jwt token
                        this.setAuth(res);
                        // successful login
                        return true;
                    }

                    // failed login
                    return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');
                }),
                catchError(error => {
                    return new Observable<any>(error);
                })
            );
        }

    // performs the logout
    logout(): boolean {
        this.setAuth(null);
        return true;
    }

    // Persist auth into localStorage or removes it if a NULL argument is given
    setAuth(auth: TokenResponse | null): boolean {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            if (auth) {
                localStorage.setItem(
                    this.authKey,
                    JSON.stringify(auth));
            }
            else {
                localStorage.removeItem(this.authKey);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Retrieves the auth JSON object (or NULL if none)
    getAuth(): TokenResponse | null {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            var i = localStorage.getItem(this.authKey);
            if (i) {
                return JSON.parse(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Returns TRUE if the user is logged in, FALSE otherwise.
    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            return localStorage.getItem(this.authKey) != null;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**TokenController**

```
[HttpPost("Auth")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Auth([FromBody]TokenRequestViewModel model)
{
    // return a generic HTTP Status 500 (server Error)
    // if the client payload is invalid.
    if (model == null) return new StatusCodeResult(500);

    switch (model.grant_type)
    {
        case "password":
            return await GetToken(model);
        default:
            // not supported - return a HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)
            return new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
}

private async Task<IActionResult> GetToken(TokenRequestViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        // check if there's an user with the given username
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.username);
        // fallback to support e-mail address instead of username
        if (user == null && model.username.Contains("@"))
            user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.username);
        if (user == null || !await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.password))
        {
            // user does not exists or password mismatch
            return new UnauthorizedResult();
        }

        // username & password matches: create and return the Jwt token
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // add the registered claims for JWT (RFC7519)
        // For more info, see...
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, new DateTimeOffset(now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString())

            // TODO add additional claims here
        };

        var tokenExpirationMins = Configuration.GetValue<int>("Auth:Jwt:TokenExpirationInMinutes");
        var issuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Key"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Audicnete"],
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: now,
                expires:
                    now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenExpirationMins)),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(issuerSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );
        var encodedToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        // build & return the response
        var response = new TokenResponseViewModel()
        {
            token = encodedToken,
            expiration = tokenExpirationMins
        };
        return Json(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

EDIT - response, inspected with POSTMAN

```
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJlODBiNzRkMi0xOGIwLTQ5NzUtOWUyYS0wOGJiOGJlOTUzMDEiLCJqdGkiOiIzNTkzNjVhYS02M2UyLTQ3ZGMtYjY1NC1mMDk3YWQxNjNmMzQiLCJpYXQiOiIxNTMwNzEzMzU2IiwibmJmIjoxNTMwNzEzMzU2LCJleHAiOjE1MzU4OTczNTYsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MzE3NzkvIn0.6QlGCK_4ybzYEz8qaRDDotOja6x0FI0fZTxmky94S5Y",
    "expiration": 86400
}

Status 200 OK
Time:11281 ms
Size:671 B

Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 04 Jul 2018 14:09:21 GMT
Server →Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
```

Comment: Have you checked your actual response?

Comment: @AlexRiabov yes, I got a valid json object. I edited the question showing the response I get testing with postman

Comment: Did you try to catch the response for the request from your app? E.g. in DevTools in Chrome

Comment: Also, added a `console.log(res)` just before the `token` line to see if the `res` was really empty, but it is ok: `Object {token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI4Z…kvIn0.KXJ_SmrqhJF1oclEUcI05F7-S4DSLHVDz-R6fRVKwt8", expiration: 86400}` That's why I think it has to do with the conversion and the TokenResponse interface, but property names and datatype match

Comment: Are you seeing `Unauthorized` in your console ?

Comment: @trichetriche no, I don't see any unathorized.

Comment: shouldn't it be just 'return this.http.post(url, data)... '?

Comment: Then I get ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/app/services/auth.service.ts:35:44 
    TS2339: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'.`` It expects a type definition

Comment: "the line `let token = res && res.token;` goes false for the if so it never gets identified" → next line you throw an error, so if it's false, why aren't you seeing the error thrown ? Please explain what error you are facing. If you don't know, please make a [mcve] on stackblitz to reproduce your issue.

Comment: And by the way, your `catchError` is misleading, you're erasing your error by returning a valid observable instead of an error

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to use the Stackblitz webapp to create an ASP .NET Core app with Angular 6. In  case you want to check it, I have the code in Github: https://github.com/blfuentes/_.NET/tree/master/NetCoreAngularWeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there were a couple of issues here.
First, my version of Chrome was breaking the VS Studio Debugger. I had to update it to a 63+ Version (65 in my case)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cd1aa58-d986-4d03-a10e-bf1fd62080a7/simultaneous-debugging-in-chrome?forum=vsdebug#5cd1aa58-d986-4d03-a10e-bf1fd62080a7

After this, I could debug better and I found the errors.

1- auth.service.ts . `throwError` function in `Observable` 
https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

```
return this.http.post<TokenResponse>(url, data)
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
                let token = res && res.token;
                if (token) {
                    this.setAuth(res);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    //failed login
                    return Observable.throwError('Unauthorized');
                }

            }),
            catchError(error => {
                //console.log(error);
                return new Observable<any>(error);
            })
        );
```

2- Typo error in TokenController `Audiecnete` instead of `Audience`

```
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Issuer"],
                    audience: Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Audience"],
                    claims: claims,
                    notBefore: now,
                    expires:
                        now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenExpirationMins)),
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(issuerSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );
```